# Google App Engine with Ajax: Test the returned data

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine

I used to use the following Ajax code for the HTML element `<a class="getContent" href="/content">...</a>`:

```
$('.getContent').click(function() { 
  var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
  $('#content').load(url); 
  return false; 
});
```

If I would like to refresh the whole page depending on the value returned by the server:

```
$('.getContent').click(function() { 
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  if (url == "success") {
    document.location.reload(true);
  }else{
    $('#content').load(url);
  }
  return false; 
});
```

Of course, the if part is just hypothetical. As I am working on Google App Engine with python, the server-side script may be:

```
if ...:
  self.response.out.write('success')
else:
  render(self, 'some_html_file.html')
```

How how do I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var menuId = $("ul.nav").first().attr("id");
var request = $.ajax({
  url: url, //your url here
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $('#content').html( msg );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  //reload here
});
```

source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/